# How to preserve pixels when placing 96 PPI image file on 72 PPI Illustrator document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, ppi

I have a 256x256 PNG file with 96 PPI. My document has raster effects set to 72 PPI.

When I place the file on the document, the linked file selection shows dimensions of 192x192 (which is 256 * 72 / 96).

Will I get scaling artifacts if I resize the linked file to 256x256, or should I first convert the image file to 72PPI outside of Illustrator?

Or, is there a way to define the PPI of a placed file?

I intend to make a color-accurate mosaic from the pixels, so I'd like to preserve the image's 256x256 pixels, one-for-one.

Answer (score 1):

Raster effect setting applies to raster effects, not imports. Illustrator has no PPI setting the image comes in at exactly as many pixels as it originally had. The pitch of pixels will just be different, just scale the image up.

Best not think there being pixel sized units in illustrator.